# extract lines when 4th column has a value within a number range

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to extract all the lines in a file that contain in the 4th column a value within a range (I have to do it several times, with different ranges). I'm trying the following command with `awk`, but it's not working:

```
awk '$4 ~ /[250898-251953]/ {print $0}' myfile.txt > myfile2.txt
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of input and expected output in code tags and let us know then.

Answer (score 5):

A regex character class accepts a range of *characters,* not numbers. `[1-35]` matches a single character which is between `1` and `3` (so, `1` or `2` or `3`) or `5`.

You want:

```
awk '$4 >= 250898 && $4 <= 251953' myfile.txt >myfile2.txt
```

`{ print $0 }` is the default action so you don't need to spell that out explicitly.

Incidentally, a single `awk` script can handle multiple ranges in one go.

```
awk '$4 >= 12 && $4 <= 34 { print >"range1" }
    $4 >= 56 && $4 <= 78 { print >"range2" }
    # etc etc' myfile.txt
```

This breaks down if the number of ranges is bigger than the number of file handles your OS allows you to keep open concurrently. You can write a more complex `awk` script, or if it's a one-off or at least a rare task, just break the task into a number of small `awk` scripts which process some 20 ranges each (which is a typical limit for how many open file handles you can have; but consult your local OS documentation to verify the precise limit on your platform).

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$4 >=250898 && $4 <= 251953{print $0}' file
```

or

```
awk '$4 >=250898 && $4 <= 251953' file
```

Note that `[0-9]` means digits from 0 to 9, whereas `[0-19]` means digits from 0 to 1 and also 9. *(Not 19)*